# PHP is not echoing the data from AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

index.js

```
$(document).on("click", ".player", function(){
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
  var values = $(id).serialize();
  $.post('./connections/lobby.class.php', { data: values }, function(data) {
    alert(id);
    });
});
```

lobby.class.php

```
public function userPublicInfo()
    {
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM account WHERE id='$this->id'");
        $stmt->execute();
        $rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo $rows['UserID'];

    }
```

game.php

```
<?php
include_once "connections/db.php";
$lobby->lobbySession();
$lobby->userPublicInfo();
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
Rest of my html code pretty much
```

When I press on the players name in the lobby, it does catch the ID.
For example: https://i.gyazo.com/9187b3d75a4633d564b51b0678444e1c.mp4

So as you can see, the Jquery click function is grabbing the appropriate ID's for the PHP mysql data called.

Now when I pass the id through Ajax, and try to echo the id or use it in a query, it doesn't work.  I got this to work in a different project, but in this one it's not.

What am I doing wrong? Need help

Comment: Shouldn't './connections/lobby.class.php' be '../connections/lobby.class.php'?

Comment: And should't  alert(id); be  alert(data); ?

Comment: @J.Rajamäki Stragely enough, for Javascript files; it never works like that.  It says file not found.  But with what I have it does read the file. https://i.gyazo.com/36c35d4a9bc93f144bbe30395f786493.png

Comment: Right. You're declaring the response as `data`, not `id`.

Comment: @KelvinSamuel It outputs nothing when its changed to data instead of id.  https://i.gyazo.com/d3b799a03e9a66b701a2416ba228129d.png , so im not sure what im doing wrong

Comment: In that case, isn't there something wrong with your query? Try echoing something else to test the Ajax instead of the actual result. Also, you're calling the input as `$(id)` when it should be `$('#' + id)`. I don't think it's even sending the request correctly.

Comment: I think `$.post` should point somewhere instead of `'./connections/lobby.class.php'`

Comment: @KelvinSamuel Yeah a random string ("test") outputs.  So im assuming its the query.

Comment: Have you changed the way you select the input? That way it's selecting an element with the id as a tag, not as an actual element `id`.

Comment: @KelvinSamuel I changed the jquery to this https://i.gyazo.com/639ce0f620bbaa57e39d1d1d1fe2df41.png

And my function is https://i.gyazo.com/a210ca8bf874e8966f5f55453b7123a1.png

I should note that my function is within a class if it matters.
So it must be my query but im trying to figure it out

Comment: I'm pretty sure that your `$.post` should be pointed to `game.php` instead of `lobby.class.php`

Comment: @Braggae is right. Also, try logging `values` to the console to see if the values you're sending are correct (e.g. the input name, which you're selecting as `id` in the PHP file).

Comment: Tried like 5 different things, nothing is working

Comment: @JordanBrown what is `.player` attached to, a form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1$.post` should point to a file not the class.

**1. Change `$.post` to point to some file**, in my example I'm using `game.php`

```
$(document).on("click", ".player", function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var values = $(id).serialize();
    $.post('game.php', { data: values }, function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

**2. Lobby.class.php**

```
<?php


class Lobby
{
    private $db;
    private $id;

    public function __construct($db, $id)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function userPublicInfo()
    {
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM account WHERE id='$this->id'");
        $stmt->execute();
        $rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo $rows['id'];

    }
}
```

**3. game.php file**

```
<?php

$id = $_POST['data'];

include_once "connections/db.php";
include_once "Lobby.class.php";

$lobby = new Lobby($conn, $id);

//$lobby->lobbySession();
echo $lobby->userPublicInfo();
```

Comment: Even though I solved it myself about 10 minutes ago.  You're solution is super similar to what I did myself.  So, you can just get correct answer for your effort.

Thank you a lot dude :)